# Back button on pages with tabs

Tags: php, jquery, sql, tabs

I'm doing a system where the pages are displayed by tabs (easytabs Plugin http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/#tabs1-js)

At one point in the process it performs a query in the database, where we
see all the details of each item that appears. I'd like to go into the details of the item, click back to the (on broswer or a button) the page to return to the list displayed by the SQL query, just as with any single page, but currently it only displays a blank page.

I wonder how can I do to implement this solution using the layout tabs.

Thank you.

Comment: We're going to need some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to maintain UI state. One of them is using a "url hash". For example, you click tab 2, change the url hash to:

mypage.php#tab=2

Then if someone presses BACK and goes FORWARD, you use JavaScript to look at the URL has and determine that the user had previously pressed tab 2, so you run your own bit of code that triggers the same event.

I'm unfamiliar with "easytabs" so I'm sorry I can't help with the specific implementation details, but that's the gist of the technique.

Comment: Tks. Change the tab I can do, I do not know when it is back showing the same query the database that had been displayed (without having to redo the select). There needs to be with this plugin.